# Tensorflow error upon training model (on GPU)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, gpu

I am using [Tanner Gilbert Tensorflow tutorial](https://github.com/TannerGilbert/Tensorflow-Object-Detection-API-Train-Model), I have solved all bugs so far to get me to last stage of actually training, at step 6, and I receive this error, that is the last part of the error message, any fixes anyone?

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.
Node:{{node HashTableV2}}
All kernels registered for op HashTableV2 :
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_INT32]; value_dtype in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_INT32]; value_dtype in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_INT32]; value_dtype in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_INT32]; value_dtype in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_INT64]; value_dtype in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_INT64]; value_dtype in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_INT64]; value_dtype in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_INT64]; value_dtype in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_INT64]; value_dtype in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_STRING]; value_dtype in [DT_BOOL]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_STRING]; value_dtype in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_STRING]; value_dtype in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_STRING]; value_dtype in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_STRING]; value_dtype in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; key_dtype in [DT_STRING]; value_dtype in [DT_STRING]
 [Op:HashTableV2] name: hash_table
```

Answer (score 0):

In his video tutorial, he says you can use batch_size values 4,8,etc according to gpu strength. But he types 1 in his code on screen, I changed from 4 to 1 and training is now working